# PHP remove duplicates and sum of them from array based on 2 keys

Tags: php, arrays

Having the below array, I'd like to have a new array without duplicates based on `parent_type` and `parent_id` keys. The `amount` needs to be a sum of them.

```php
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [amount] => 12000.00
                [parent_type] => company
                [parent_id] => 11
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [amount] => 12000.00
                [parent_type] => taken_service_agreement
                [parent_id] => 15
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [amount] => 1233.00
                [parent_type] => company
                [parent_id] => 13
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [amount] => 1233.00
                [parent_type] => taken_service_agreement
                [parent_id] => 16
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [amount] => 100.00
                [parent_type] => taken_service_agreement
                [parent_id] => 16
            )

        [5] => Array
            (
                [amount] => 0
                [parent_type] => company
                [parent_id] => 13
            )

    )
```

I'd like to have

```php
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [amount] => 12000.00
            [parent_type] => company
            [parent_id] => 11
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [amount] => 12000.00
            [parent_type] => taken_service_agreement
            [parent_id] => 15
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [amount] => 1233.00
            [parent_type] => company
            [parent_id] => 13
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [amount] => 1333.00
            [parent_type] => taken_service_agreement
            [parent_id] => 16
        )

)
```

All solutions I've found regards to 1 key match.

Comment: Show what you tried. We're here to help you fix your code, not write it for you.

Comment: A version of the dupe for your specific case: https://3v4l.org/5GPAu